# How to tune the hyperparameters for time series data using models built with pytorch

Tags: performance, time-series, cross-validation, hyperparameters

I have read many posts related to the time-series data with walk forward validation. I am currently facing the issue as to how to split the data. I have to monitor previous 5 days data to predict the class of the current day data. There are two classes 0 or 1 i.e. either the price will go up or down. I have already the entire data windowed for 5 days with every window having the label of the next day as its label.

I want to keep 20% data in the test set and 80% data as training data for the final model evaluation. Now how do I apply walk-forward validation with grid-search of the hyper-parameters? keeping 20% data in training and next 20% in test always will generate 4 such models giving final model ie. 4th model as 80% training data and 20% test data. Let's say we have 100 windowed samples then

```
train | test 
model1  - 20|20
model2  - 20+20|20
model3  - 20+20+20|20
model4  - 20+20+20+20|20


or it is like 
model1 - 80|1
model2 - 81|1
model3 - 82|1
model4 - 83|1
.
.
.
model20 - 99|1
```

Further, the performance score will be mean score across all the models for every configuration of grid-search. Also, every model will be trained for 100 epochs which will be lot of time. So can we just evaluate multiple time steps at once?

I am new to time-series hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.